How can I update previous object keys while iterating through a single loop?
I am trying to solve the following challenge:

Description
Given an input string, count occurrences of a given emoji (encoded as :apple:) for each user after encountering their user name (encoded as <@User />). If a user does not have any of the given emoji, they inherit the count from the next user in the sequence. This process continues until all emoji occurrences are found, and those are then assigned to all users in the group that lack them.
The input string and the emoji (without the colons) are passed as argument to the function countEmoji(message, emoji). This function should return an object that has a key (lowercase) for each encoded user, and the corresponding number of emojis found for that user.
Example
Input:

message = '<@Kate />:apple: <@Max/>sometext<@alisa /> :like: received:apple::apple:'
`emoji = 'apple'

Expected output:
{
    kate: 1,
    max: 2,
    alisa: 2
}

Emoji valid pattern:
A valid emoji is a text (not case sensitive) delimited on both sides by a colon. For example :apple:
It should have no spaces. There is no sharing of colons between emoji. So :apple:apple: only has one valid emoji.
Examples:

:apple: encodes 1 apple
:aPPle::aPpLe: encodes 2 apples
:apple:apple:   encodes 1 apple
:apple : encodes 0 apples
:  Apple   : encodes 0 apples

Name pattern:
A valid name is encoded as <@Name /> without spaces in or before the name, where the varying Name must consist of only English letters, and is not considered case sensitive. There can be spaces before the ending />. So <@namee  />  is valid.
Requirements

Use only 1 for loop, with all iteration in one loop.
Only use character codes for parsing.
Use 1 object to store the results (no additional arrays or objects are allowed).
Use charCodeAt to identify necessary characters and fromCharCode to convert to lowercase.
Can't use JavaScript methods other than those mentioned (No map, filter, ...), and no for...in loop.


Main problem
I can keep track of the previous username, but how do I handle a long chain of usernames?
Using a for...in loop would make this easy, but I am restricted to only using a single for loop.
My code
function countEmoji(message, emoji) {
  const ASCII = {
    numFirstCharCode: 48,
    numLastCharCode: 57,
    openBracket: 60,
    closeBracket: 62,
    atSign: 64,
    slash: 47,
    toLowerOffest: 32,
    upperCaseStart: 65,
    upperCaseEnd: 90,
    lowerCaseStart: 97,
    lowerCaseEnd: 122,
    space: 32,
    colon: 58,
  };

  let result = {};

  let name = "";
  let isNameCreated = false;
  let nameCreationStage = 0;

  let emojiFounded = 0;
  let emojiStage = -1;

  function toLowerCase(char) {
    const isInUpperCase =
      ASCII.upperCaseStart <= char && char <= ASCII.upperCaseEnd;
    if (isInUpperCase) {
      return String.fromCharCode(char + ASCII.toLowerOffest);
    }
    return char;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    const charCode = message.charAt(i).charCodeAt();
    const isInLowerCase =
      ASCII.lowerCaseStart <= charCode && charCode <= ASCII.lowerCaseEnd;
    const isInUpperCase =
      ASCII.upperCaseStart <= charCode && charCode <= ASCII.upperCaseEnd;

    if (!isNameCreated) {
      if (charCode === ASCII.openBracket && nameCreationStage === 0) {
        nameCreationStage++;
      } else if (charCode === ASCII.atSign && nameCreationStage === 1) {
        nameCreationStage++;
      } else if ((isInUpperCase || isInLowerCase) && nameCreationStage === 2) {
        if (isInLowerCase) {
          name += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        } else if (isInUpperCase) {
          name += String.fromCharCode(charCode + ASCII.toLowerOffest);
        }
      } else if (name) {
        if (charCode === ASCII.space) {
          continue;
        } else if (charCode === ASCII.slash) {
          nameCreationStage++;
        } else if (charCode === ASCII.closeBracket && nameCreationStage === 3) {
          nameCreationStage = 0;
          isNameCreated = true;
        }
      }
      continue;
    }

    if (isNameCreated) {
      //search for pattern start - :
      if (charCode === ASCII.colon && emojiStage === -1) {
        emojiStage++;
        continue;
      }
      if (emojiStage - (emoji.length - 1) === 1) {
        if (charCode === ASCII.colon) {
          emojiFounded++;
          emojiStage = -1;
          continue;
        }
      }
      //start compering symbols
      if (charCode === toLowerCase(emoji.charAt(emojiStage).charCodeAt())) {
        emojiStage++;
        continue;
      } else {
        if (charCode === ASCII.openBracket && nameCreationStage === 0) {
          nameCreationStage++;
          isNameCreated = false;
          result = { ...result,
            [name]: emojiFounded
          };
          name = "";
          emojiFounded = 0;
        }
        emojiStage = -1;
      }
    }
  }
  result = { ...result,
    [name]: emojiFounded
  };
  return result;
}

const text = '<@Kate />:apple: <@Max/>sometext<@alisa /> :like: received:apple::apple:';
const emoji = "apple";

console.log(countEmoji(text, emoji));

My code returns {kate: 1, max: 0; alisa: 2}, but this has the wrong number for max. It should be 2.
How can I do this without an extra loop and within all the requirements?

Yes, I am allowed to use recursion.

You can build a loop with recursion. Recursion allows you to use as many loops as you want. It's as simple as function loop(begin, end, cb) { cb(begin); if (begin < end) loop(++begin, end, cb); }. cb is the loop body.

It is not really nice to change the details of the question after it has been answered. countBananas makes no sense, because banana is what the second argument to that function could get as value, but it could also be apple, house, or whatever emoji-name. So the function doesn't count bananas, it counts emojis. Also, changing the example names is unnecessary. You also removed the capitalisation, which was informative to see the case-insensivity at work. There was also a needed colon removed. For these reasons I reverted your edit -- it made the post worse.

You could use recursion. Every time you match a name tag, you could make a recursive call and get back a count of emojis, which is the number of emojis that follow that tag until the next name tag (or the end of the string). As you unwind from recursion, you still have the username for which you made the recursive call, and thus are in a position to update that user's emoji-count.
Here is an implementation:


const ASCII = {
    numFirstCharCode: 48,
    numLastCharCode: 57,
    openBracket: 60,
    closeBracket: 62,
    atSign: 64,
    slash: 47,
    toLowerOffset: 32,
    upperCaseStart: 65,
    upperCaseEnd: 90,
    lowerCaseStart: 97,
    lowerCaseEnd: 122,
    space: 32,
    colon: 58,
};

function toLowerCase(ch) {
    return ch >= ASCII.upperCaseStart && ch <= ASCII.upperCaseEnd 
         ? ch + ASCII.toLowerOffset
         : ch;
}

function isLetter(ch) {
    return ch >= ASCII.lowerCaseStart && ch <= ASCII.lowerCaseEnd;
}

function process(message, emoji, start, result) {
    let emojiCounted = 0; // Number of emoji counted from the start index onwards, before the next name tag
    let emojiIndex = -1;   // Number of characters matched of the emoji (-1 = no colon yet)
    let name = "";        // Letters constituting a (partial) tag name
    let nameReadingStage = 0; /* 0: did not encounter (part of) a name tag yet; 
                                 1: found "<@" followed by 0 or more letters; 
                                 2: found "<@" followed by 0 or more letters, followed by 1 or more spaces */
   
    for (let i = start; i < message.length; i++) {
        const ch = toLowerCase(message.charCodeAt(i));
        if (ch === ASCII.colon) {
            nameReadingStage = 0;
            if (emojiIndex === emoji.length) { // We have matched an emoji
                emojiIndex = -1;
                emojiCounted++;
            } else {
                emojiIndex = 0; // At the start of a potential emoji
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (ch === toLowerCase(emoji.charCodeAt(emojiIndex))) { // Matching the emoji
            nameReadingStage = 0;
            emojiIndex++;
            continue;
        }
        emojiIndex = -1;
        const ahead = toLowerCase(message.charCodeAt(i+1));
        if (ch === ASCII.openBracket && ahead === ASCII.atSign) {
            i++;
            nameReadingStage = 1;
            name = "";
        } else if (nameReadingStage === 1 && isLetter(ch)) {
            name += String.fromCharCode(ch);
        } else if (nameReadingStage > 0 && ch == ASCII.space) {
            nameReadingStage = 2; // From now on only spaces are allowed before tag closure
        } else if (nameReadingStage > 0 && name && ch === ASCII.slash && ahead === ASCII.closeBracket) {
            result[name] = 0; // Create a key now (so we maintain key order)
            // Use recursion to process the rest of the message and update this key
            result[name] = process(message, emoji, i+2, result);
            emojiCounted ||= result[name]; // Override zero with what we got back
            break;
        } else {
            nameReadingStage = 0;
        }
    }
    return emojiCounted;
}

function countEmoji(message, emoji) {
    const result = {};
    process(message, emoji, 0, result);
    return result;
}

// Demo
const text = '<@Kate />:apple: <@Max />sometext :apple <@alisa /> :like: received:apple::apple:';
const result = countEmoji(text, "apple");
console.log(result);



